# Как выполнить условие, если другое условие выполняется несколько раз подряд?

Tags: python

**Есть условие:**

```
    if lastprice < PRICEnow:
        signal = "РАСТЁТ"

        print('Цена '+ str(signal) +': '+ str(PRICEnow), 'Средства: '+ str(round(BANKUSDLIVE, 2))+' $  ', 'Прибыль: '+ str(round(STOCK, 2))+' $  ', str(FULLDATE))
```

**Как установить выполнение нового условия,  если условие выше выполнится например 10 раз ПОДРЯД ?**

Comment: Исходя из Вашего кода условие выше может выполнить только 1 раз... а так `else if` конструкция или ниже написать еще одно `if` (вложенное или нет по обстоятельствам)

Answer (score 1):

```
    counter = 0
    ...
    if lastprice < PRICEnow:
        signal = "РАСТЁТ"
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 0

    if counter == 10:
    ...
```